# Absolute Mathematica beginner have fundamental question

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm working through all the problems in Elementary Introduction to Wolfram language and I'm running into a fundamental problem I could use help with.

An example, "Make a list of the first 10 squares, in which each value is styled at its size."

In this problem we are generating a list, and then we want to apply an operation to each element of the list where the operation itself is a list. First, we generate a list of the first 10 squares. Next generate a list of the first 10 squares to use as the Size argument in the Style function.

In Wolfram Table[x^2, {x, 1, 10}] will generate a list of the first 10 squares.

Style[Table[x^2, {x, 1, 10}], {1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81,100}] will apply the size 100 to each element of the list.

In other words Style takes only a single argument, in this case it only takes the last value 100 and applies it to the list of the first 10 squares.

I'm essentially asking how do I iterate so that I am running the Style function on each successive square applying each successive size. I'm not sure if I'm formulating the question correctly.

thank you for the help.

I tried listing the values explicitly

Style[Table[x^2, {x, 1, 10}], {1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81,100}]

and I tried generating the values with table.

Style[Table[x^2, {x, 1, 10}], Table[n^2, {n, 1, 10}]]

in both cases it only applies the size 100

Comment: Thanks. I've tried Table[Style[Table[x^2, {x, 10}], n], {Table[n^2, {n, 10}]}]
I think this is where my confusion comes in. I am submitting as the second Table argument a table itself- and I'm not sure that's allowed.

Comment: So Close!
Table[Style[x^2, x], {x, 10}]
A few very important points. I didn't realize Style could take a variable that was defined outside the Style function, in this case x. However, this doesn't Style each member with their font size equal to their value, i.e. 49 in FONT size 49. It just uses 1-10 for Font size. Still working on it.

Comment: Table[Style[x^2, x^2], {x, 10}]

Got it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Table[Style[x^2, x^2], {x, 10}]

Comment: And if typing `x^2` twice makes your fingers tired you could try `Table[Style[#, #] &[x^2], {x, 10}]` which probably takes you further into the *Elementary Introduction*.

Comment: Hey thank you ! I’ve seen the # symbol in the documentation but hadn’t quite figured out its use.